# Where to put bin, include and lib directories from virtual environment into development repository?

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv

I have a Django project which I've been running on a local virtual environment, [here's how the root directory looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1NnC.png) (`draft1` is my app). I'm now ready to push this project to a repo so I can start to develop it on a public server - so my question is - where do the `bin`, `include` and `lib` directories go? How do they translate from local development to when using a public server?

Comment: You shouldn't ship your virtual environment (and its binaries) along with your project. Instead, just ship the project requirements (in `requirements.txt` or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't ship with your dependencies, just ship with the requirements.txt, and make sure you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in a virtual env in server everytime you deploy.